# Reference to non-static function must be called

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I tried to declare a priority_queue:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::function<bool(int, int)>> m_openList;
```

and the way I use to initialize it is:

```
m_openList = std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::function<bool(int,int)>>(keyCompare);
```

keyCompare is a function:

```
bool PathPlanManager::keyCompare(int pointer1, int pointer2) {
    return m_mapNode[pointer1] > m_mapNode[pointer2];}
```

But it seems wrong. BTW, how can I clear this priority_queue?

After I tried, my code was like this:

```
class PathPlanManager {
public:
class KeyCompare {
    public:
        KeyCompare(PathPlanManager& manager) : m_manager(&manager){}
        bool operator() (int pointer1, int pointer2) {
            return m_manager->m_nodeMap[pointer1] < m_manager->m_nodeMap[pointer2];
        }
    private:
    PathPlanManager* m_manager;
    };
    void init() {
        m_nodeMap.resize(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            m_nodeMap[i] = 100 - i;
        }
        m_openList = std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, KeyCompare>();
    }
private:
    vector<int> m_nodeMap;
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, KeyCompare> m_openList;
};
```

And when I tried to build it, there is an error says No matching constructor for initialization of 'value_compare'(aka 'PathPlanManager::KeyCompare')

Comment: PathPlan::KeyCompare::operator() is a function that belong to the PathPlan::KeyCompare struct, thus, it cannot access the private member of PathPlan as they are different object.

Comment: No, the problem is still here when I set vector<int> m_nodeMap as public

Comment: Yes, because you consider that KeyCompare has direct access to PathPlan. Or it has not. You could set a static variable of KeyCompare that has access to the instance of PathPlan you try to sort for example.

Comment: I still cannot figure out how to solve this problem, and I have put my code up here. Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: Conserning *No matching constructor for initialization of 'value_compare'(aka 'PathPlanManager::KeyCompare')*: you don't have a default constructor defined for `KeyCompare` and because you don't initialise `m_openList` in the constructor of `PathPlanManager` `std::priority_queue` tries to instantiate `KeyCompare()`. Simply define a default constructor or initialise the queue in the constructor of `PathPlanManager` like I showed you below.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyCompare` needs an object of `PathPlanManager`:

```
class PathPlanManager {
public:
    class KeyCompare {
    public:
        KeyCompare(PathPlanManager& manager) : m_manager(&manager) { }
        bool operator()(int pointer1, int pointer2) {
            return m_manager->m_mapNode[pointer1] > m_manager->m_mapNode[pointer2];
        }
    private:
        PathPlanManager* m_manager;
    };
private:
    std::vector<int> m_mapNode;
    typedef std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, KeyCompare> mypq_type;
    mypq_type m_openList;
}
```

Example usage:

```
PathPlanManager mgr; // somewhere this is initialised
...
// want to sort some entries according to mgr
std::vector<int> entries{ 0, 13, 37, 42 };
std::sort(entries.begin(), entries.end(), PathPlanManager::KeyCompare(mgr));
// now entries is sorted according to mgr
```

After seeing your update: if you want to use `priority_map` as a member of a class (let's call it `Planner`) you can do it like this:

```
class Planner {
public:
    Planner(PathPlanManager& mgr);
private:
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, PathPlanManager::KeyCompare> m_openList;
}

Planner::Planner(PathPlanManager& mgr)
 : m_openList(PathPlanManager::KeyCompare(mgr))
 { }

// Usage:
...
PathPlanManager mgr;
Planner planner(mgr);
...
```

Comment: I follow your way and it shows an error: No matching constructor for initialization of KeyCompare

Comment: @YunfeiLu I added an usage example, post your full error message and the code where the error occurred.